# React {...props} sideEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a ReactComponentParent that receives 15 different props (objects, numbers, booleans, arrays, etc)

Inside ReactComponentParent I have a ReactComponentChild that requires 6 props but instead I am using {...props}

```
<ReactComponentChild {...props} />
```

Is there any side-effect (performance-wise talking) using {...props} instead of just the needed props?
Is react somehow, maybe via propsTypes, handling this behaviour?
Should I just send just what the component needs?

Comment: Enforces that there is no spreading for any JSX attribute. This enhances readability of code by being more explicit about what props are received by the component. It is also good for maintainability by avoiding passing unintentional extra props and allowing react to emit warnings when invalid HTML props are passed to HTML elements.
[ESlint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md)

Comment: @ayxos passing **unnecessary props** might lead to unnecessary-re-render ...

Answer (score 0):

This way you are sending all props coming from parent to Child component like

```
<ReactComponentChild {...props} />
```

A good approach is to just send needed props to Child